# How many subsets of {1, 2, 3, ... 10} do not contain any pair of consecutive integers?

Tags: combinatorics

How would I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Please just give the number for the answer instead of strategies, those are really unhelpful. If this is a duplicate please put a link for the answered question.

I just want a number for the answer, so far this website has been really unhelpful.

Comment: @Math1000 I don't really understand that solution, and I just want a number and solution for this specific case of n=10.

Comment: There are few enough you can just list and count them.  It will take a little while, but you might see the pattern.  If you put in $1$ you can't put in $2$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Such a subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$  either does not contain $n$ and hence is such a subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$, or it contains $10$ and the rest is such a subset of $\{1,2,\ldots, n-2\}$. Use his to find a recursion formula and recognize this. as famous